# How to make python not to break dataframe-description into blocks?

Tags: python, pandas, transpose

The bellow code outputs the df-description into two blocks, though the display.max_rows and display.max_columns is set to a high value.
I'd like to print it without the breaks. Is there any way to do it?

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)

data = {'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Height': [120, 121, 119, 118],
        'Very_very_long_variable_name': [40, 71, 49, 78]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.describe().transpose())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this setting as well on the top:

```
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
```

And now:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 1000)

data = {'Age': [20, 21, 19, 18],
        'Height': [120, 121, 119, 118],
        'Very_very_long_variable_name': [40, 71, 49, 78]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.describe().transpose())
```

Output:

```
                              count   mean        std    min     25%    50%     75%    max
Age                             4.0   19.5   1.290994   18.0   18.75   19.5   20.25   21.0
Height                          4.0  119.5   1.290994  118.0  118.75  119.5  120.25  121.0
Very_very_long_variable_name    4.0   59.5  17.935068   40.0   46.75   60.0   72.75   78.0
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any option, just use the "to_string" method:

```
print(df.describe().T.to_string())
```

output:

```
                              count   mean        std    min     25%    50%     75%    max
Age                             4.0   19.5   1.290994   18.0   18.75   19.5   20.25   21.0
Height                          4.0  119.5   1.290994  118.0  118.75  119.5  120.25  121.0
Very_very_long_variable_name    4.0   59.5  17.935068   40.0   46.75   60.0   72.75   78.0
```